Need help on replacing faucets of bathroom sink
I am trying to replace both faucets of the sink but I found there is a connecting tube between these 2 under the hood.
What exactly is the tube called? And how am I supposed to detach it from the faucet?
Your help is greatly appreciated and thank you!



A picture from above would help. You mention two faucets but it appears the hot and cold may mix in that center pipe and tee up to one central faucet. Strange setup to my eye but I think that once you turn off the water and start disassembling it from below (1) disconnect water supply lines, and (2) loosen white flange nuts, how to remove the center pipe might become more obvious. The valve housings above may simply unscrew from what you see below.

@HoneyDo Added the picture

You don't detach that. It's brazed together, and was installed already brazed together from the factory.
You remove the parts above that hold it in the counter and lower the entire assembly to remove.
